# Getting Coffee Script Compilation Syntax Error after Upgrading to Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-6

After upgrading from Rails `5.2.4.2` to Rails `6.0.2.2` I am now getting a coffee script compilation error, but ExecJs does not specify the file where it is occurring:

I haven't made any other changes to my codebase beyond upgrading my gems.

```
  Error during failsafe response: SyntaxError: [stdin]:1:14: missing / (unclosed regex)
  compile ((execjs):7528:19)
  eval (eval at <anonymous> ((execjs):7539:8), <anonymous>:1:10)
  (execjs):7539:8
  (execjs):7545:14
  (execjs):1:40
  Object.<anonymous> ((execjs):1:58)
  Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
  Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
  Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
  Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
  Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
  internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:39:in `exec'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:21:in `eval'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:46:in `call'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/coffee-script-2.4.1/lib/coffee_script.rb:78:in `compile'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/coffee_script_processor.rb:24:in `block in call'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/cache.rb:92:in `fetch'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/coffee_script_processor.rb:23:in `call'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:22:in `block in <class:CompositeProcessor>'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:33:in `call'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:182:in `load_from_unloaded'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:59:in `block in load'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:335:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:43:in `load'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `load'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:41:in `block in call'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:167:in `dfs'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:42:in `call'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:182:in `load_from_unloaded'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:59:in `block in load'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:335:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:43:in `load'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `load'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:81:in `find_asset'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:88:in `find_all_linked_assets'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in find'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/safe_task_executor.rb:24:in `block in execute'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:41:in `block in synchronize'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:41:in `synchronize'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:41:in `synchronize'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/safe_task_executor.rb:19:in `execute'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promise.rb:563:in `block in realize'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:353:in `run_task'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:342:in `block (3 levels) in create_worker'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:325:in `loop'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:325:in `block (2 levels) in create_worker'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:324:in `catch'
  /Users/sean297/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:324:in `block in create_worker'
```

```
assets/javascripts/application.js

//= require media.match.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.mb.browser.min.js
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.remotipart
//= require bootstrap/bootstrap
//= require bootstrap/bootstrap_overrides
//= require jquery-ui
//= require datatables/jquery.dataTables
//= require js/highcharts
//= require jquery_placeholder/jquery.placeholder
//= require jquery.scrollTo
//= require enquire.js
//= require media.queries.js
//= require_directory .
//= require handlebars/handlebars-4.0.5
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
//= require results_mailers/results_mailers.js
//= require schedule/table.js
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker.validation.min.js
//= require jquery.dynamic-form
```

```
assets/config/manifest.js

//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../javascripts .js
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
```

```
rails (6.0.2.2)
coffee-rails (4.2.2)
  coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
  railties (>= 4.0.0)
coffee-script (2.4.1)
  coffee-script-source
  execjs
coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
```

Edit: after attempting to use decaffeinate, I believe that the syntax error is here:

```
//= require ./date_time_picker.js
//= require ./jquery-ui-sortable.js
//= require ./bootstrap_multiselect.js
//= require ./spectrum.js

$ ->
  $(".color-control").spectrum({
    preferredFormat: "hex"
  })

  $('[rel="tooltip"],[data-rel="tooltip"],[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
  $('[rel="popover"],[data-rel="popover"],[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
```

It doesn't like the `//=` ...

Answer (score 0):

The two things I'd look at is:

A. Ensure `sprockets` is still installed on your project. Not sure how you went about the upgrade, but you might have to explicitly require `require "sprockets/railtie"`.

B. Is this code in a file labeled with `<filename>.coffee.erb`?

It's looking like rails isn't processing this file as ERB before processing it as Coffeescript, which points to either Sprockets not being there or this file not being parsed correctly for whatever reason.